# what is the best way to inject multiple interface in Constructor Injection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

On an ASP.NET MVC solution I have a Service layer which contains services for each Model. For example for DocumentModel I have Document Service which is instantiated by a UoW class which acts like a factory and does the save:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private IRepositoryFactory _repositoryFactory;

    public UnitOfWork()
        : this(new RepositoryFactory())
    {

    }

    public UnitOfWork(IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)
    {
        _repositoryFactory = repositoryFactory;
    }

    private IDocumentService _DocumentService;
    public IDocumentService DocumentService
    {
        get
        {
            if (_DocumentService == null)
            {
                _DocumentService = new DocumentService(_repositoryFactory.DocumentRepository);
            }
            return _DocumentService;
        }
    }
}
```

Now say I need to be able to access 2 or 3 other repositories from DocumentService. What is the best way to inject this new  repositories? Add them in the constructor( which if I need to add yet another repository can become cumbersome) or should I just inject the repository factory (IRepositoryFactory) which will allow me to access in DocumentService any repository I may need.

Comment: Your `UnitOfWork` contains a `Service` instance? why?

Comment: My UnitOfWork is over Services because I have 3 layers in my application: 1.Asp.Net MVC-->Core(Contains UoW over the services and the services + Models) ->3.DAL(contains EF+repositories + repository factory). My Web project doesnt know anything about repositories and all the business logic I try to keep in core services.